# How do scroll up with a number of lines at a time with tmux?

Tags: vim, tmux

I have my tmux set up for scrolling using vim shortcuts. I can go up a page at a time.

However, I am faced with a very long test failure log. I went up once with `Ctrl+U` multiple times and realized that this was about `5000` lines higher. I made changes and go the same error. I would like to read the early portions of this error message again (this is C++ so the more useful stuff is at the beginning) and was wondering if I can specify the `5000`-line difference to go back up.

If it is possible, is there a way to change this number in case I get a different error and then find out that it is `8000` vs `5000` lines higher?

Comment: This sounds like a task for Vim's quickfix feature.